# Related rate problem. Is my setup correct?

Tags: calculus

> A street light is mounted at the top of a $15-$ft-tall pole. A man
>   $6$ ft tall walks away from the pole with a speed of $5$ ft/s along a straight path. How fast is the tip of his shadow moving when he is $40$ ft from the pole?

So this is confusing because we have heights ($6$ and $15$) and speeds. How do we related this together to determine the speed that we are trying to determine?

Is the setup this:

$$\frac{x}{x+y} = \frac{6}{15}$$

Why? I found this setup but I'm confused about it. What is $x + y$? What is $x$? Are we not using $40$ at all?

Answer (score 1):

If the man's distance from the pole is $x$, then his shadow tip's distance from the pole will be $5x/3$. Draw a figure to see this: let the length of his shadow (i.e. the distance between the man and his shadow tip) be $y$. You'll see that $\frac{x+y}{15} = \frac{y}{6}$, and $x+y$ is the distance of the shadow tip from the pole.

Since $dx/dt = 5\ ft/s$, $\frac{d(5x/3)}{dt} = \frac{25}{3}\ ft/s$. His distance from the pole is irrelevant.

Comment: What is y? Isn't that 40?

Comment: $y$ is the distance between the man and the shadow tip, or basically the length of the man's shadow. $x$ equals $40$ because it's defined as the man's distance from the pole.

Comment: So then $15y = 6x + 6y$ and then $9y = 6x$ so $3/2y = x$. Where did you get that $x + y = 5x/3?$

Comment: @Jwan622: Read the answer carefully. I've written that $\frac{x+y}{15} = \frac{y}{6}$. If you're referring to the last 2 equations in my answer, I've used the fact that $dx/dt = r \implies d(ax)/dt = adx/dt = ar$. In this case, $a = 5/3$ and $r=5$.